# Plot a third point past the two previously plotted points. Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Ok so let me try to explain this the best way that i can.

I have two points plotted 'A' and 'B' and I am trying to plot a third point 'C' so that it is past point 'B' but along the same slope. I have the angle of the line and I would post some code but I really have no idea where to begin.

any help would be awesome!

Just a little code that i do have

```
CGPoint vector = ccpSub(touchedPoint, fixedPoint);
CGFloat rotateAngle = -ccpToAngle(vector);
```

Comment: You mean you want all 3 points to be colinear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that by this you mean you need a 3rd point C added such that all the points are colinear, all you need to do is calculate the vector that takes you from A to B, and then generate a new point by adding multiples of this vector to the point B. Choose the multiple based on the distance you want C to be from B.

As an example, say A = (2,2), B = (4,3). Then the vector from A to B is given by (2,1).

All you need to do then is work out how far your new point is from B and add a multiple K*(2,1) to your point B where K is chosen to meet the requirements of your distance

I am assuming you are in 2D, but the same method would apply in higher dimensions

Answer (score 1):

My math is rusty, but the linear equation is generally represented as y=m*x+b, where m is the slope, and b is the y-intercept. You can get m, the slope, by taking the difference of the y values and dividing that by the difference in the x values, e.g., if A = (2,2) and B = (4,3), then m is (3-2)/(4-2) or 0.5. Then, you can solve the linear equation for b, the y-intercept, i.e. b=y-m*x and then plug in either of the data points, e.g. if we plug in the x and y values for point A, you get b = 2 - 0.5 * 2 = 1. Now knowing the slope, m (0.5 in this example), and the y-intercept, b (1 in this example), you can calculate the y for any x value using y=m*x+b, in this case y=0.5*x+1.

So, if touchedPoint and fixedPoint are CGPoint, you can calculate the slope and y-intercept from fixedPoint and touchedPoint like so:

```
double m = (fixedPoint.y - touchedPoint.y) / (fixedPoint.x - touchedPoint.x);
double b = fixedPoint.y - m * fixedPoint.x;
```

Now, you don't say how you want to determine where this third point, C, is. But if you, for example, knew the x coordinate for this new point C, you can calculate the y coordinate that falls on the same line as follows:

```
CGPoint pointC;
pointC.x = 400; // or set this to whatever you want
pointC.y = m * pointC.x + b;
```